# Count Vowels in List of Strings

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and doing my best to solve and practice a lot. I have faced a problem while practicing and found no solution.

```
var list = List("Scala","combines","object-    
                oriented","and","functional","programming","in","one","concise", 
                "high-level", "language")

def getCount(inputStr: List[String]): Int = {
    val vowelsList = List('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') 
    inputStr.map(x => x.contains(vowelsList)).length 
}
getCount(list)

// Expected Output = 32
// Output = 11
```

I know it counts only the words, but how is it possible to iterate at every possible char and check if it's a vowel or not? (in Scala)

Comment: Hint: a `String` is a `List[Char]`. Flatten your `List[String]` to `List[Char]` and you can count based on a criteria.

Comment: By the way, dealing with text is *hard*. For example, `w` and `y` are vowels in Welsh (Cymraeg). So, you would need to figure out the language of the words first in order to even know which characters are vowels and which aren't. Also, for example, in Dutch, `ij` is a *single* vowel, so it only counts as 1. And then there's languages where `æ`, `ø`, `å` are vowels. Turkish distinguishes between `I` with dot and without, so the lowercase version of `I` is actually `ı` and the uppercase version of `i` is actually `İ`.

Comment: And let's not even dive into the whole discussion that technically, vowels aren't a property of *writing* at all, they are a property of *speaking*. In other words, whether something is a vowel or not, depends on how it *sounds*.

Comment: @GaëlJ, actually String is array of char, and since Java 9 it's actually array of bytes... but we can assume that string like list of Char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more lower-level way of doing it: just put a `1` in a list for every occurrence found and sum it up at the end:

```
  def getCount(words: List[String]): Int = {
    val listOfOnes = for {
      word <- words
      c    <- word
      if vowels.contains(c.toLower)
    } yield 1

    listOfOnes.sum
  }

  println(getCount(words)) // 32
```

There are a lot of ways to solve it, you should try solving it in more than one way to really get a feeling about how powerful the language is.
Gael's idea is indeed much more elegant:

```
  println(words.flatten.count(c => vowels.contains(c.toLower))) // 32
```

or

```
  println(words.mkString.count(c => vowels.contains(c.toLower))) // 32
```

Say `count` did not exist. You could do it, for example, like this:

```
  println(words.flatten.foldLeft(0) { (acc, c) =>
    if (vowels.contains(c.toLower)) acc + 1 else acc
  }) // 32
```

Comment: Amazing detailed explanation. Really helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In Scala, you can think of a string as a sequence of characters. In reality, in most Scala implementations, strings are actually implemented by the hosting platform (e.g. on the JVM, strings are actually JVM [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html)s and on [Scala.js](https://scala-js.org/), they are actually ECMAScript [`string`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string-objects)s), but there are usually some implicit conversions and possibly some compiler trickery as well to make them look like they are native Scala types and implement [all the native Scala collection APIs](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html).

So, a [list](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#) of strings is really two collections nested inside each other, and you can flatten these nested collections out to a single collection using the [`flatten`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#flatten-5d3) method:

```scala
list.flatten
//=> List(S, c, a, l, a, c, o, m, b, i, n, e, s, o, b, j, e, c, t, -, o, r, i, e, n, t, e, d, a, n, d, f, u, n, c, t, i, o, n, a, l, p, r, o, g, r, a, m, m, i, n, g, i, n, o, n, e, c, o, n, c, i, s, e, h, i, g, h, -, l, e, v, e, l, l, a, n, g, u, a, g, e)
```

Now that you have a flat list, you can just use the [`count`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#count-db6) method to count the number of elements that satisfy a given *predicate* (i.e. a [function](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/Function1.html#) from the element type to [`Boolean`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/Boolean.html#)).

A nice feature of Scala's collections API is that [`Set`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/Set.html#)s are actually *predicates*! I.e. [a `Set` object is actually a function which tells you whether an element is a member of the `Set`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/Set.html#apply-4ad).

If we combine those two features together, we end up with something like this:

```scala
val vowels = Set('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

list.flatten.count(vowels)
//=> 32
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to just count the number of vowels of each word and then `sum` the results.

```scala
def countVowels(words: List[String]): Int = {
  val vowels = Set('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

  words.map(word => word.count(c => vowels.contains(c.toLower))).sum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution to the count one is to filter the string for vowels and find its size:

```
"abcdefghijk".filter("aeiouAEIOU".contains(_)).size
```

The `_` is an anonymous variable that simplifies `c => [...].contains(c)` in the case that `c` occurs only once in the expression.

Comment: `filter+size` is just unefficient `count`, and it is LMMS solution (he answered 4 hours after you)

Comment: Also the first answer had count - it was more about using `_` to shorten it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another variation:

```
def countVowels(words: List[String]): Int = {
  words.foldLeft(0) { (count, word) =>
    count + word.count(c => vowels.contains(c.toLower))
  }
}
```

The advantage of this one is that you traverse the overall collection (each string in the list and each character in each string) only once whereas flattening and counting after flattening requires two separate traversals.